# mu4e (gnus) MS safelinks decoder

Tags: microsoft-windows, gnus, mu4e, hyperlinks

Today I got scared after noticing how many [Microsoft ATP Safelinks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/atp-safe-links?view=o365-worldwide) had made their way into my org-mode calendar file. Therefore, is it possible to create a URL decoder to bypass Microsoft Safelinks for mu4e(gnus)? There are implementations for other mail-clients in [Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504003/decoding-microsoft-safelink-url-in-python) and [Javascript](https://github.com/antsar/unsafelinks) but elisp (if possible) would be preferable. I am using mu4e 1.4.1 and emacs 26.3. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Thanks wasamasa. To wire it up to mu4e I've developed a url reader (below), based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982387/is-there-a-urlview-a-la-mutt-for-gnus-or-just-elisp-for-extracting-urls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer, based on code from Wasamasa and Joseph Gay.

**Post version 1.6.0~54**

```lisp
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;             Microsoft safelinks decoder                            ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(require 'url-parse)
(defun my-decode-safelink (url)
  ;; (print url)
  "Given a url string this function returns the corresponding decoded url"
  (if (string-match-p (regexp-quote "safelinks.protection") url)
      (let* ((query (url-filename (url-generic-parse-url url)))
             (url (cadr (assoc ".*/?url" (url-parse-query-string query) (lambda (pat x) (string-match-p x pat)))))
             (path (replace-regexp-in-string "3Dhttps" "https" (url-unhex-string url))))
        (url-encode-url (replace-regexp-in-string (rx "/" (>= 20 (any "#$%&*^@"))) "" path)))
    url))

;; Main function
(defun unsafelinks ()
  "This function filters MS safelinks from a message buffer"
  (interactive)
  (let (url current-start-pos next-change-pos)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let ((inhibit-read-only t)
            (simple-url-regexp "https?://") urls)
        (search-forward-regexp "^$" nil t)
        (setq next-change-pos (or (next-single-property-change (point) 'shr-url)
                                  (point-max)))
        (goto-char next-change-pos)
    
        (while (< next-change-pos (point-max))
          (setq url               (get-text-property (point) 'shr-url)
                current-start-pos (point)
                next-change-pos   (or (next-single-property-change (point) 'shr-url)
                                      (point-max)))
          (when url
            (setq text (buffer-substring-no-properties current-start-pos (point)))
            ;; edit widget URLs
            (add-text-properties current-start-pos next-change-pos
                                 (list 'shr-url (my-decode-safelink url)
                                       'help-echo (my-decode-safelink url)))
            ;; edit text URLs
            (when-let ((link (thing-at-point 'url))
                       (bounds (thing-at-point-bounds-of-url-at-point)))
              (delete-region (car bounds) (cdr bounds))
              (insert (my-decode-safelink url)))
            )
          (goto-char next-change-pos))
        (remove-overlays)
        (mu4e~view-activate-urls)
        (set-buffer-modified-p nil)))))

(defun unsafelinks-advice (msg)
  (unsafelinks))
(advice-add #'mu4e~view-render-buffer :after #'unsafelinks-advice)
```

**Previous to version 1.6.0~123**

```lisp
;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Microsoft safelinks decoder
;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(require 'url-parse)
(defun my-decode-safelink (url)
  "Given a url string this function returns the corresponding decoded url"
  (if (string-match-p (regexp-quote "safelinks.protection") url)      
      (let* ((query (url-filename (url-generic-parse-url url)))
         (url (cadr (assoc "/?url" (url-parse-query-string query))))
         (path (url-unhex-string url)))
    (replace-regexp-in-string (rx "/" (>= 20 (any "#$%&*^@"))) "" path))
    url))

(defun unsafelinks (vmode)
  "This function filters MS safelinks from a message buffer"
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (let ((simple-url-regexp "https?://") urls)
    (save-excursion
      ;; edit text URLs
      (while (search-forward-regexp simple-url-regexp nil t)
    (when-let ((url (thing-at-point 'url))
           (bounds (thing-at-point-bounds-of-url-at-point)))
      (delete-region (car bounds) (cdr bounds))
      (insert (my-decode-safelink url))))
      ;; edit widget URLs
      (beginning-of-buffer)
      (while (not (eobp)) 
    (goto-char (next-overlay-change (point)))
    (when-let (link (get-text-property (point) 'shr-url))             
      (and (string-match simple-url-regexp link) 
           ;; change overlay url echo
           (when (overlay-put (car (overlays-at (point))) 'help-echo (my-decode-safelink link)) t)
           ;; change url text-properties 
           (add-text-properties (point) (next-overlay-change (point)) (list 'shr-url (my-decode-safelink link) 'help-echo (my-decode-safelink link))) 
           ))
    (goto-char (next-overlay-change (point))))
      (when vmode (gnus-article-prepare-display)
        (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
        (read-only-mode))))
    (mu4e-compose-goto-top))

;; Append it to mu4e view and compose mode hooks
(add-hook 'mu4e-view-mode-hook (lambda () (unsafelinks t)) t)
(add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook (lambda () (unsafelinks nil)) t)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've ported the Python code you've linked:

```lisp
(require 'url-parse)

(defun my-decode-safelink (url)
  (if (string-match-p (regexp-quote "safelinks.protection.outlook.com") url)
      (let* ((query (url-filename (url-generic-parse-url url)))
             (url (cadr (assoc "/?url" (url-parse-query-string query))))
             (path (url-unhex-string url)))
        (replace-regexp-in-string (rx "/" (>= 20 (any "#$%&*^@"))) "" path))
    url))

(my-decode-safelink "https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Foffice.memoriesflower.com%2FPermission%2F%2525%2524%255E%2526%2526*%2523%2523%255E%2524%2525%255E%2526%255E*%2526%2523%255E%2525%2525%2526%2540%255E*%2523%2526%255E%2525%2523%2526%2540%2525*%255E%2540%255E%2523%2525%255E%2540%2526%2525*%255E%2540%2Foffice.php&data=01%7C01%7Cdavid.levin%40mheducation.com%7C0ac9a3770fe64fbb21fb08d50764c401%7Cf919b1efc0c347358fca0928ec39d8d5%7C0&sdata=PEoDOerQnha%2FACafNx8JAep8O9MdllcKCsHET2Ye%2B4%3D&reserved=0")
;; "https://office.memoriesflower.com/Permission/office.php"

(my-decode-safelink "https://office.memoriesflower.com/Permission/office.php")

;; "https://office.memoriesflower.com/Permission/office.php"
```

That leaves the part of wiring it up to mu4e.