# Apply buffer-local function inside another function in temporary buffer

Tags: org-mode, gnus, mu4e

Elisp newbie here,

I am trying to filter MS safelinks from an org-mode icalendar event, which gets saved by the `gnus-icalendar:org-event-save` function. I have created a function that filters the [MS safelinks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58268/mu4e-gnus-ms-safelinks-decoder) and am now trying to apply it to the buffer created inside `gnus-icalendar:org-event-save`. I have tried unsuccessfully to 1) run it as a hook, and 2) re-define the function as

```lisp
(defun gnus-icalendar:org-event-save (event reply-status)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (org-capture-string (gnus-icalendar-event->org-entry event reply-status)
            gnus-icalendar-org-template-key)
    (unsafelinks nil)))
```

When I have MS safelinks in `*scratch*` and eval `(unsafelinks nil)` the links get filtered, so I don't understand why the above setup doesn't work. Probably it is an obvious mistake from someone learning elisp. Thank you in advance.

**Update**

Per request of wasamasa, the text to be filtered out is returned by the function `(gnus-icalendar-event->org-entry event reply-status)`.

Comment: Try adding `unsafelinks` to `org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook`, does that do the trick?

Comment: Aside, it would help to know what text exactly needs filtering. The initial text provided to the capture buffer by `(gnus-icalendar-event->org-entry event reply-status)`? The text you enter there yourself?

Comment: "I have created a buffer-local function" -- there is no such thing as a buffer-local function.  Only variables can be buffer-local.  You could assign a function object to a buffer-local variable, but it's *really* not clear what you actually meant.

Comment: Sweet @wasamasa. The `org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook` was spot on. Thank you very much! THis is what I've used `(add-hook 'org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook (lambda () (unsafelinks nil)) t)`. Add it to a reply and I'll accept it

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @phils. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure at what point your text comes in, but since this is org-capture, you can use `org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook` to do postprocessing like this:

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook (lambda () (unsafelinks nil)))
```

Note that this does the postprocessing globally, so consider using the fourth argument of `add-hook` to do it locally or write a named hook function removing itself from the hook after it's done.

edit: In light of the update, here's an alternative way of doing this without hooks:

```
(defun unsafelinks-string (string vmode)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert string)
    (unsafelinks vmode)
    (buffer-string)))

(with-eval-after-load 'gnus-icalendar
  (defun gnus-icalendar:org-event-save (event reply-status)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (org-capture-string (unsafelinks-string
                           (gnus-icalendar-event->org-entry event reply-status)
                           nil)
                          gnus-icalendar-org-template-key))))
```

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity. I've detailed what text I want to have filtered out. Will add that to the question.

Comment: The alternative does not work. It is missing `vmode` in gnus-icalendar:org-event-save (which can be nil for the present case), but aside from that, the links are not being filtered.

Comment: Found the issue and it's my fault. I should have called `(beggining-of-buffer)` before the search for urls in unsafelinks. With that modification your alternative solution works 100%. Just learned something new, and I will update the unsafelinks function in my other post. Thanks once again.